# Not able to inspect blackberry 7, native application in google chrome

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, blackberry, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I have made a Blackberry 7, native application. It is working fine in Ripple emulator. But, after making it to .jad file, and installing in Blackberry 7 mobile. Then I am getting some some style problems. So, I want to inspect the Blackberry 7 mobile apps to computer google chrome. So, I have follow this steps in command prompt-

`i).bbwp D:\BB7_Source\myapp.zip /d -g my_password -o
D:\BB7_Output,`

`ii). Install the package into bb7`

After that I am able to launch the application. It is showing me ip address and port number. When I am using this ip address and port number in my computer browser google chrome. It is not able to find the input ip address. Even, my mobile is connected with my computer using USB. and using Wi-Fi connection. I am using splash screen in my bb7 native apps. So, after following all the steps, I am not able to inspect my bb7 native apps in my computer.

Comment: Is web inspector working for you in the browser on your phone? I assume you've only mis-typed it here as you're getting the ip and port numbers, but there is supposed to be a '-d' in the bbwp command.

Comment: Thanks! It is not working in browser also. You are correct, we should use '-d'. But, it is for bb Tablet OS not for bb Smartphone. For Smartphone we have to use '/d'. You can find more from - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-debug-BlackBerry-web-applications-using-Web-Inspector/ta-p/1207155   . And it is true that I am getting ip and port number.